# Why does $\frac{1}{\Delta x} \int^{x+\Delta x}_x f(u) du$ tend to $f(x)$ as $\Delta x \to 0$? (From proof of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I was reading a proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus in my textbook and one of the lines states that $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta x} \int^{x+\Delta x}_x f(u) du = f(x)$$ but it didn't give any explanation for this. The section on limits is later in the books so I assume this can be understood with only basic knowledge of limits.

For context, here is the poof up to this step:

$$
\begin{align} 
F(x) &= \int^x_a f(u) du \\
F(x+\Delta x) &= \int^x_a f(u) du + \int^{x+\Delta x}_x f(u) du\\
&= F(x) + \int^{x + \Delta x}_x f(u) du \\
\frac{F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)}{\Delta x} &= \frac{1}{\Delta x} \int^{x+\Delta x}_x f(u) du\\
\Delta x &\to 0 \\
&\therefore \\
\frac{dF}{dx} &= f(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is true provided $f$ is continuous at $x$.  I assume that was stated before these calculations.

Comment: This is what one calls the first part of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. And it holds more generally. If $f(u) \to A$ as $u\to x^+$ then the expression in question tends to $A$ as $\Delta x\to 0^+$ and a similar relation holds for $\Delta x\to 0^-$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 
\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int^{x+\Delta x}_x f(u) du
$$

Using the mean value theorem for integrals:

$$\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\Delta x}f(c)(\Delta x +x-x)
$$
For some constant $c$ inside the interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$

$$
\Longrightarrow f(c)
$$

Since $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$, $c$ also approaches $x$ (as it is squeezed between the said interval)

Hence $$\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int^{x+\Delta x}_x f(u) du = f(x) $$
as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Of course the mean value theorem for integrals requires $f$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to think about it: Let $M_{\Delta x}$ and $m_{\Delta x}$ be the supremum and infimum of $f$ over the interval $[x,x + \Delta x]$.  We have
$$
    m_{\Delta x} \cdot \Delta x \leq \int_{x}^{x + \Delta x} f(u)\,du \leq M_{\Delta x} \cdot \Delta x
$$
So
$$
    m_{\Delta x} \leq \frac{1}{\Delta x} \int_{x}^{x + \Delta x} f(u)\,du \leq M_{\Delta x}
$$
Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} M_{\Delta x} = f(x)$ and similarly for $m_{\Delta x}$.  So by the squeeze theorem, the term in the middle tends to $f(x)$ too.

Comment: (+1), but shouldn't $M_{\Delta x}$ and $m_{\Delta x}$ be the supremum and infimum of $f$ on the interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$, not $f(x)$?

Comment: @Joe yes, absolutely.  I'm more used to thinking of $x$ as a variable ranging over an interval than an endpoint of that interval, and in my haste I was doing both.  Let me edit.

Comment: Great! I slightly prefer this approach to using the Mean Value Theorem, because the inequality you used follows directly from how integrals are defined in the first place.